# Web form using PHP is sending spam even with CAPTCHA

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form on my website that has started sending through a lot of spam even though the Captcha on it works.

I have noticed that the spammer (trying to put links up to cheap training shoes even though our form is not posted to a blog) uses the captcha text repeatedly in filling out the form.

I would like a way to check if and entry is the same for three form field and reject the mail at that point. It has got to the point where we are missing genuine enquiries.

I tried the check for blank hidden field way of detecting spam and this did not work

I use a standard script using a public domain image generator called `CaptchaSecurityImages.php` which has worked well up till now here is an example of the SPAM

```
Submit: Submit    
Name: T Shirt Women Summer    
Email: *******@gmail.com   
Address Line 1: ksjj22   
Address Line 2: ksjj22   
Town: ksjj22    
City: ksjj22    
Postcode: ksjj22    
Telephone: ksjj22    
Make: ksjj22    
Model: ksjj22   
Registration: ksjj22
Collection Date: ksjj22
Security code: ksjj22
Other information: Great post but I was wanting to know if you could write a litte more on this topic? I'd be very grateful if you could elaborate a little bit further. Cheers!
<a href="spam web address" >T Shirt Women Summer</a> [url=spam web address]T Shirt Women Summer[/url]
```

any help gratefully received.

Comment: Sounds like either your Captcha is not good enough, or it is a real person with too much time..............

Comment: Are you sure the mails come from your form? The reason why I ask is, that we had the same problem once, but they just imitated our mail and didn't send them via our contact form

Comment: What CAPTCHA do you have?

Comment: We are using captcahsecurityimages.php which has been great up till now!  what I have noticed is the spammer reading the code the pastes it into most fields I would like a way to commpare say 'City' 'postcode' and 'telephone' and if equal just reject and let them carry on but not see the emails

Comment: I would say you are under attack from the world famous **PainInTheA$%£** bot. In other words a plain old human being.

Answer (score 3):

> I use a standard script using a public domain image generator called CaptchaSecurityImages.php

The more wide-spread your Turing test, the more chance a bot has explicitly targeted it, and is able to break it. Image recognition scripts are surprisingly advanced, and are getting more advanced all the time. Making an image "hard" to read for a computer, is surprisingly difficult in 2014.

What I have done on several *small* websites, is to do:

```
Please enter the number 42 here to prove you're a human: [   ]
```

This has worked surprisingly well, so far. In the code, all you need to do is check if the number matches, so it's very easy to implement, and will work for all your customers (including those who may be blind, or have other accessibility needs), which is not always the case with image-based Turing tests ("CAPTCHA" being the hip word I believe).

This works because parsing a line of text, figuring out the meaning, and giving the correct answer, is still a hard problem for computers (although this may change in the future), so even a very simple question such as this will suffice.

You could also expand on this, and ask simple questions, such as *"What year is it"*, or *"how much is six by seven"*. You want to make sure that your target audience has a good change of actually knowing the answer.

You can, of course, alternate between all of this randomly. So far, I haven't had a need to do this, though, and I would recommend starting by just asking the simple question.

Note that this will only work for comparatively *small* websites. As soon as your website or product reaches a certain size, it becomes interesting enough to target explicitly; at which point a human sits down, and writes a bot to answer all the questions you've written down.
However, from your description I think your website is "small enough" for this.

Comment: I am not the greatest PHP programmer is there a simple way to compare inputs and reject the mail without notifying the sender

Comment: @PaulPayne The simplest way is to do `if ((int) $_POST['turing_test'] !== 42) { exit(1); }`, but you probably want to show an error in case if typos

Comment: Did a small change if the phone number equals the captcha code as has been happening the code exits seems to be working so far thanks for your help with this

Comment: I used this<br> $Telephone = $_POST['Telephone'];
$Security_code = $_POST['security_code'];
if($Telephone == $Security_code)  { exit(1); }

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to implement [HoneyPot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_%28computing%29). Honeypot main idea is to have an empty input form that is hidden. Spam bots will fill out every input field with some value even if it's hidden with css. You can then call `isempty()` in your php submit form. If its not, then you have spam. This is a hassle free alternative to capta.

At any rate, this does not prevent attackers from spamming if they set up a bot specifically for your site. If you still receive attacks. Grab the IP address of the one sending the information, then block them if they post more than 5 times. And if you have the IP address of a repeated offender, you can block that IP address from accessing the site at all.

Comment: What about accessibility for blind people ?

Comment: HI I tried the hidden field and we ere still getting the SPAM

Comment: Will try the IP check starting today Thanks

Comment: The problem with IP blocks is that you can't reliably get an IP; you **will** accidentally block innocent customers unless you're *very* careful and aware of all the caveats here.

Comment: @L.Wartel This can be made slightly better by having a hidden label with the text "Please do not fill this in, or the form won't work", or somesuch. It's not perfect, but better than just an input sitting there...

Comment: Thanks for the warning Carpetsmoker

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following code to detect the spam submissions. For the problem we have been having which seems to be one or two actual people entering information into the form on our site the following identifies the use of the captcha code in the phone field (it was being used for most fields) and dumps the script out preventing our inbox getting filled with SPAM (hopefully the spammer does not know this is the case)

```
$Telephone = $_POST['Telephone'];
$Security_code = $_POST['security_code'];

if ($Telephone == $Security_code) 

   header("Location: /");
else
```